# Sumifs with multiple criteria or sum the total range

Tags: excel, sumifs

The data I need to sum is based on 2 validation drop down list selections that a user can choose from. The choices include a Total or individual criteria.

The formula also pulls data from a specific date range.

```
=SUMIFS(imp,rawdatadate,"<="&E$6,rawdatadate,">="&E$7,rawdatatarget,H3,rawdatapublisher,L3
```

rawdatatarget and rawdatapublisher are the named ranges for the criteria that the lists H3 and L3 selections will use to total imp.

Not sure if I am going about this the right way, but for the h3 and L3 lists, the selections include Total (if the user does not wish to get granular data).

It seems as though If statements do not allow you to used named ranges in the logical test for matching purposes (examples =if(h3=rawdatatarget...)

So how can I sum a total of a range, or the total based on two different list criteria?

Thanks.

Comment: is rawdatadate a date range ?

Comment: it is a column with a date for each row. The above formula is looking for dates between a certain range. So $e$6 and $e$7 are the dates the users selects.